# Mapping from Tuple to ICollection

Tags: c#, mysql, tuples, icollection

Ok so I get data from mySql and it comes back as a ReadOnlyCollection`<Tuple<DbAudit, DbAuditItem>>`. Now I have to map from this to my `Audit` and `AuditItem` classes. The `Audit` part is working like so:

```
return audits.Select((AuditMapper.Map)).ToReadOnlyCollection();
```

and in the auditmapper this happens.

```
public static Audit Map(Tuple<DbAudit, DbAuditItem> source)
{
  if (source == null)
    return null;

  return new Audit(
    null,
    (AuditKind) source.Item1.AuditKindId,
    source.Item1.DateCreated,
    null,
    source.Item1.ContainerItemId,
    source.Item1.UserId,
    Item2.Select(AuditItemMapper.Map).ToReadOnlyCollection()
);
}
```

but the Item2.Select... line isn't working and i'm not sure how else to write it.  Any ideas?

EDIT:
First the Item2 line is supposed to be source.Item2.Select.

I've also realized my logic isn't making sense because each Item2 is only one auditItem and i'm trying to add it to a collection. Audit item looks like this:

```
public Audit(string applicationToken, AuditKind auditKind, DateTime dateCreated, string containerName, string containerItemId, int userId, ICollection<AuditItem> auditItems)
    {
        m_applicationToken = applicationToken;
        m_auditKind = auditKind;
        m_dateCreated = dateCreated;
        m_containerName = containerName;
        m_containerItemId = containerItemId;
        m_userId = userId;
        m_auditItems = auditItems;
    }
```

and the auditItem is:

```
public AuditItem(string name, string data, string oldData)
    {
        m_name = name;
        m_data = data;
        m_oldData = oldData;
    }
```

But I see that the way I have is isn't going to work. I need somehow to take each distinct Item1 of the tuple and put each corresponding Item2  into a collection that will go into the audit item...

Comment: What do you mean "Item2.Select isn't working"? Compile error? Not expected result? Exception? 42?

Comment: Have you tried `source.Item2` ?

Comment: Also, you have one AuditItem in the tuple but treat them as a collection. We need more information in the nature of the two classes relationship

Comment: Could you please post the Audit and AuditItem constructor code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing it in a roundabout way like so:

```
Audit audit = null;
            List<AuditItem> auditItemsList = new List<AuditItem>();

            List<Audit> totalAudits = new List<Audit>();

            ulong thisId = 0;

            foreach (Tuple<DbAudit, DbAuditItem> tuple in audits)
            {
                if (tuple.Item1.Id == thisId)
                {
                    auditItemsList.Add(AuditItemMapper.Map(tuple.Item2));
                }
                else
                {
                    if (thisId != 0 && audit != null)
                    {
                        totalAudits.Add(new Audit(audit.ApplicationToken, audit.AuditKind, audit.DateCreated, audit.ContainerName, audit.ContainerItemId, audit.UserId, auditItemsList));
                        auditItemsList.Clear();
                    }
                    thisId = tuple.Item1.Id;
                    audit = (AuditMapper.Map(tuple.Item1));
                    auditItemsList.Add(AuditItemMapper.Map(tuple.Item2));
                }
            }
```